# Ruby Connected Components in a Graph

Tags: ruby, algorithm, graph-theory

I've written the following code to find the connected components of a graph in ruby, but it is quite slow since I don't use any sensible data structure for the disjoint sets, and so find_set is probably O(n^2)

Can anybody help me improve it? I am relatively new to ruby. This code is meant to solve the problem posed [Here:](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/torque-and-development/problem)

My solution, in plain English, is the find the number of connected components in the graph given, then either calculate the cost of building a library in every node or the cost of building a library in each connected component plus the cost of building the roads for the minimum spanning tree of each component.

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'set'

def roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities)
  vertices = make_set((1..n).to_a)

  #find connected components    
  cities.each do |a, b|
    first_set = find_set(vertices, a)
    second_set = find_set(vertices, b)
    if first_set != second_set
      vertices.add(first_set | second_set)
      vertices.delete(first_set)
      vertices.delete(second_set)
    end
  end

  #calculate the cost of building the edges required for a MST of each component
  roads_cost = c_road * vertices.to_a.map{|x| x.size - 1}.inject(:+)

  if c_road > c_lib
    return n * c_lib
  else
    return vertices.size * c_lib + roads_cost
  end

end


def make_set(arr_n)
  vertices = Set.new
  for i in 1..arr_n.size
    vertices.add([i])
  end
  vertices.map!{|x| x.to_set}
end

def find_set(set, node)
  set.find{|x| x.include?(node)}
end





# q is number of queries, n is the number of vertices in the graph 
q = gets.strip.to_i
for a0 in (0..q-1)
  n, m, c_lib, c_road = gets.strip.split(' ')
  n = n.to_i
  m = m.to_i
  c_lib = c_lib.to_i
  c_road = c_road.to_i
  cities = Array.new(m)
  for cities_i in (0..m-1)
    cities_t = gets.strip
    cities[cities_i] = cities_t.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
  end
  result = roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities)
  puts result
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If it works but can be optimized, you should post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/